Multiply two dataframes in pandas
I have two pandas df:




A
B
C




A
1
2
3


B
3
3
1


C
2
1
1



and




d
e




d
0.2
0.3


e
0.1
0.4



I want to "multiply" second df by first and get this:
      A        B       C
    d   e   d   e    d    e
A d 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6  0.6  0.9
  e 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.8  0.3  0.12
B d 0.6 0.9 ...
  e 0.3 0.12 ...
C d 0.4 0.6 ...
  e 0.2 0.8 ...

Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks!

You can compute an Index product on both index/columns (MultiIndex.from_product), reshape and multiply:
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.columns])
idx  = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, df2.index])

out = (df1.reindex(index=idx.get_level_values(0),
                   columns=cols.get_level_values(0))
          .mul(df2.reindex(index=idx.get_level_values(1),
                           columns=cols.get_level_values(1)
                          ).values)
          .set_axis(idx).set_axis(cols, axis=1)
      )

Or using numpy broadcasting to reshape:
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.columns])
idx  = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, df2.index])

a = df1.to_numpy()[:,None,:,None]*df2.to_numpy()[None,:,None]
out = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(np.array(df1.shape)*df2.shape),
                   index=idx, columns=cols)

Output:
       A         B         C     
       d    e    d    e    d    e
A d  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.6  0.6  0.9
  e  0.1  0.4  0.2  0.8  0.3  1.2
B d  0.6  0.9  0.6  0.9  0.2  0.3
  e  0.3  1.2  0.3  1.2  0.1  0.4
C d  0.4  0.6  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.3
  e  0.2  0.8  0.1  0.4  0.1  0.4

